# Finding repeated elements in an array using .filter() - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to check what letters repeat in a string by creating a new array of only the repeated letters using the `.filter()` method but I only want the letter to appear one time, no matter how many times it repeats.

This is what I tried:

```
const fullName = "Muhammad Ali";
const fullNameLowercase = fullName.toLowerCase();
const splitName = fullNameLowercase.split("");

let repeats = splitName.filter((letter, index) => {return splitName.indexOf(letter) !== index});
console.log(repeats); // prints [ 'm', 'm', 'a', 'a' ]
```

I want it to only add the letter once to the array `repeats`, how do I do it? Is there any other more efficient way to do what I want that doesn't use `.filter()`?

Comment: what do you expect from `repeats` var?

Comment: @ElMehdi in this example I'm trying to get `['m', 'a']` instead of `[ 'm', 'm', 'a', 'a' ]`

Comment: `[...new Set(['a', 'a'])]` => `['a']`

Answer (score 1):

Simply by wrapping up `repeats` variable with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) constructor and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax): to avoid duplicates values:

```js
const fullName = "Muhammad Ali";
const fullNameLowercase = fullName.toLowerCase();
const splitName = fullNameLowercase.split("");

let repeats = splitName.filter((letter, index) => splitName.indexOf(letter) !== index);
const repeatsNoDuplicates = [... new Set(repeats)];
console.log(repeatsNoDuplicates); // prints [ 'm', 'a']
```

*Tip: use implicit return by remove the curly braces and return keyword from an arrow function it is implied that you return the expression code tells it to do.*

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other more efficient way to do what I want that doesn't use .filter()?

Sure, an efficient solution would be to use a counting hash table, run your string through it and collect keys those counts are > 1:

```js
let str = "Muhammad Ali"
let counter = new Map

for (let char of str.toLowerCase())
  counter.set(char, 1 + (counter.get(char) ?? 0))

let repeats = []

for (let [char, count] of counter)
  if (count > 1)
    repeats.push(char)
    
console.log(repeats)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it with the reduce method like so :

```js
const fullName = 'Muhammad Ali';
const fullNameLowercase = fullName.toLowerCase();
const splitName = fullNameLowercase.split('');

let repeats = splitName
  .filter((e, i) => splitName.indexOf(e) !== i)
  /* we create an empty array and for every letter :
    - if the letter is already in the array: don't do anything
    - if the letter isn't already in the array: add it to the array
    it returns us the array without duplicates
  */
  .reduce((g, c) => g.includes(c) ? g : g.concat([c]), []);
  
console.log(repeats);
```

Comment: The existing answer using a `Set` is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Add another `Array.filter()` to the end of the line:

```
filter((ltr, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(ltr)  != idx);
```

```js
const fullName = "Muhammad Ali";
const fullNameLowercase = fullName.toLowerCase();
const splitName = fullNameLowercase.split("");

let repeats = splitName.filter((letter, index) => {
  return splitName.indexOf(letter) !== index;
}).filter((ltr, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(ltr)  != idx);

console.log(repeats);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do that... ?

```js
const repeatLetters=s=>Object.keys([...s.toLowerCase()].reduce((r,c,i,a)=>((a.indexOf(c)<i)?r[c]='':'',r),{}))  

console.log( repeatLetters('Muhammad Ali') )
```

Comment: it would be more helpful to post non-minified code

Answer (score 0):

- `filter()` and `.test()` filters out any non-letter characters.
- `.reduce()` returns an object that has the count of occurrences of each letter.
- `Object.entries()` converts the object returned by `.reduce()` to an array of key/values.
- `.flatMap()` filters out any letter occurring once.

**Example B** is just a slightly smaller version of **Example A**

### Example A

```js
const string =  `"Float like a butterfly, sting like a bee."
                                             - Muhammad Ali`;

const repeats = text => {
  let letters = text.toLowerCase().split("").filter(a => /[a-z]/.test(a));
  let counts = letters.reduce((prv, cur) => {
    if (!prv[cur]) {
      prv[cur] = 1;
    } else {
      prv[cur]++;
    }
    return prv;
  }, {});
  console.log("Letter quantities: ")
  console.log(counts)
  return Object.entries(counts).flatMap(([key, val]) => val > 1 ? key : []);
}

console.log("Repeated letters: "+repeats(string));
```

### Example B

```js
const string = `"Float like a butterfly, sting like a bee."
                                             - Muhammad Ali`;

const repeats = text => {
  return Object.entries(text.toLowerCase().split("").filter(a => /[a-z]/.test(a)).reduce((prv, cur) => {
    if (!prv[cur]) prv[cur] = 1;
    else prv[cur]++;
    return prv;
  }, {})).flatMap(([key, val]) => val > 1 ? key : []);
}

console.log("Repeated letters: " + repeats(string));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[...new Set(repeats)]` as in the demo below:

```js
const fullName = "Muhammad Ali";
const fullNameLowercase = fullName.toLowerCase();
const splitName = fullNameLowercase.split("");

let repeats = [...new Set(splitName.filter((letter, index) => {return splitName.indexOf(letter) !== index}))];

console.log(repeats); // prints [ 'm', 'a' ]
```

**Alternatively ....**

You can start by obtaining all unique letters in the string and then using `Array#filter` to return those that repeat:

```js
const 
    fullName = "Muhammad Ali",
    fullNameLowercase = fullName.toLowerCase(),
    uniques = [...new Set(fullNameLowercase.split(""))],

    output = uniques.filter(l => fullNameLowercase.split(l).length > 2);
    //OR output = uniques.filter(l => fullNameLowercase.match(new RegExp(`[${l}]`,'g')).length > 1);

console.log( output ); //[ 'm', 'a' ]
```